# Can I specify the order of a SQLAlchemy foreign relationship in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following two models:

```
class Company(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "company"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    comments = db.relationship("Comment", backref="comment", lazy=True)


class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "comment"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("company.id"), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    created_datetime = db.Column(
        db.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.now
    )
```

And the following Jinja2 template:

```
{% for comment in company.comments %}
    <div><span>{{ comment.created_datetime }}:</span> {{comment.body}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'd like to order the comments by created_datetime desc.

Can I do that in the Jinja2 template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jinja2:

Ascending

```
{% for comment in company.comments|sort(attribute='created_datetime') %}
   <div><span>{{ comment.created_datetime }}:</span> {{comment.body}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Descending

```
{% for comment in company.comments|sort(attribute='created_datetime', reverse = True) %}
   <div><span>{{ comment.created_datetime }}:</span> {{comment.body}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Or do the sort in Python prior to passing `company` to the template:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # e.g company 10
    company = Company.query.join(Company.comments).filter(Company.id == 10).order_by(Comment.created_datetime.desc()).first_or_404()
    render_template('index.html', company=company)
```

Comment: Thanks. Precisely what I needed.